# Match cell value to data in another column and return adjasent value to another cell

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, match

I am trying to achieve this :

If `B56` (on Summary page) matches value in column `B` (on "NPSSQL" page) then put text from `NPSSQL` column `C` (next to matching value) in to cell `F56`

if I use this code it gives me the incorrect value in cell `F56` :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(NPSSQL!C:C,MATCH(B56,NPSSQL!B:B,0)),NPSSQL!C:C)
```

[image]

I have added sample file - [Sample File](https://app.box.com/s/f1q5ktw4m2khgv03ayc21kw9kk9deyu6)

Comment: I am going to guess that one of the columns is a number stored as text and the other is a number, and as such it does not match.  Or they are both number stored as text and one has some extra spaces on the ends.

Comment: Both B columns are numbers and column C is text but the B column on the summary page comes from a Vlookup result =VLOOKUP(A52,SPEXP!$A52:$C650,3,FALSE) so I don't know if that affects the result?

Comment: usually numbers are right aligned and text is left aligned.  Try changing the cell format to currency and see if it changes.  If not then it is a  number stored as text.

Comment: I am getting a result so the formula must see a match it is just not the correct value if I am trying to match B21 on sheet1 it is giving me result of value C21 on Sheet2 if column F

Comment: That is because you are getting an error on the INDEX MATCH and thus returning the row in which the formula is in to the `NPSSQL!C:C` in the end of the IFERROR.  Remove the IFERROR and you will get `#N/A`.  Try this put `=B56=NPSSQL!B766` this will return FALSE.  Excel is not seeing them as a match and thus an error is thrown because there is no match being found.  Remove the IFERROR till you get the INDEX/MATCH working.  It stems that Excel is not seeing them as equal.  I have given you many reasons why that could be, but without the actual data it is hard to surmise via picture.

Comment: "if I use this code it gives me the incorrect value" <-- what is the value you received?  please share sample file for better insights resolution. (:

Answer (score 1):

in F56:
=Vlookup(B56,NPSSQL!C$2:D$500,2,0)

Comment: Thanks, This gave me #N/A I have added sample file it this helps?

Comment: The file helped.... for some reason the values in column B in Summary page were captured as text. Use: =VLOOKUP(VALUE(B1),NPSSQL!$B$1:$C$15,2,0)